# How to create a collection which has a sub collection in firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know how can I create a collection in flutter that has a subcollection inside it. I know that to create a collection I use this code

```
firestore.collection('Collection').add({
    'EmployeeID': '123',
    'EmployerID': '234',
    'ProposalID': '456,
  }
```

but want to achieve something like this

```
firestore.collection('Collection').add({
    'EmployeeID': '123',
    'EmployerID': '234',
    'ProposalID': '456,
    'Chats':**THIS IS A SUB COLLECTION**
  }
```

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `add` operation can only write a single document at a time. If you need to write multiple documents, you'll need to use a batch write operation.

If you want to write the "parent" document, and the chats subcollection in a single batch write, you can do so by for example generating a UUID for the parent document, and then creating the chat documents under that same path.

```
var db= Firestore.instance();
var uuid = uuid.v1(); // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549397
firestore.collection('Collection').add(
var collectionRef = db.collection("Collection");
var batch = db.batch();
batch.setData(
  db.collection(’Collection’).document(uuid), {
    'EmployeeID': '123',
    'EmployerID': '234',
    'ProposalID': '456',
  })
);
batch.setData(
  db.collection(’Collection’).document(uuid).collection('Chats').document(uuid.v1()), {
    'Message': 'Hello world',
    'Timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  })
)
batch.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to get a specific document, to where you chain another `collection` method onto the end, which would create a document inside that collection:

```js
firestore.collection('Collection').doc("myDocId").collection("Collection2").add({
    'EmployeeID': '123',
    'EmployerID': '234',
    'ProposalID': '456,
    'Chats':**THIS IS A SUB COLLECTION**
  }
``
```

Comment: In this the collection has already been created. You are just adding data to it. I need to create a collection at random which has the subcollection "Chats" inside it.

Comment: basically I wont know the document id. It will be randomly created by firebase with 3 fields and a subcollection called chats in it

Comment: @junaidtariq would you have anyway of finding the document?

Comment: Yes I have a way of doing that