# What's the scope of an UniqueKey in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I'm an unique person. I mean I'm different from all other persons *in this world*. When I create an UniqueKey in flutter, what's the *world* in which it's different from all the others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `UniqueKey` is unique in exactly the same way that each instantiated object is a separate object.  There isn't anything magical about [the implementation of `UniqueKey`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/02c026b03cd31dd3f867e5faeb7e104cce174c5f/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L46).  A `UniqueKey` will never compare equal to another `UniqueKey` in the process, and it doesn't make sense to compare `UniqueKey`s across processes.

A `UniqueKey` is not a UUID/GUID; if you ran, say, `identityHashCode` on it and saved it, there would be no guarantee that some other object wouldn't generate the same `identityHashCode` value. (And `identityHashCode` is still ultimately a hash code, which means that two objects might generate the same hash code anyway.)

(If you're wondering if, say, a `UniqueKey` could be identical to a `UniqueKey` that was already created and garbage-collected in the process, then that'd be like a Zen koan: there'd be no way to tell since comparing it the earlier instance would require a reference to it, and a reference would have prevented it from being garbage-collected.)